# Show that $d(x, y) = |f (x) − f (y)|$ is a metric on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, metric-spaces

Prove that for any 1-1 function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, the function $d : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by
$$ d(x, y) = |f (x) − f (y)| $$
is a metric on $\mathbb R$.

I need to prove these properties:

1. $d(x,y)\ge0$
2. $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$
3. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
4. Triangle inequality: $d(x, y) + d(y, z) \ge d(x, z)$

I was able to prove first three but couldn't prove the last one.

Comment: Can you prove $|x-y|+|y-z|\geq|x-z|$? If so then you replace $x,y,z$ by $f(x),f(y),f(z)$ and you are ready. For this $f$ does not have to be 1-1. That property is only needed for $d(x,y)=0\implies x=y$.

Comment: Hint : $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f(z)+f(z)-f(y)|$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that it's true for the identity function, then:
$$|f(x)-f(z)|=|f(x)-f(y)+f(y)-f(z)|=|(f(x)-f(y))+(f(y)-f(z))|\leq |f(x)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f(z)|$$